# jquery - colorbox does not show title

Tags: jquery, ajax, colorbox

I have problems to display a link title inside a colorbox. Link is inserted by ajax response/php echo.

PHP:

```
echo "<a onclick=\"parent.\$.colorbox({ href:'inc/get_movie_details.php?m=". $row->XD_ID ."' , width:800 , maxWidth:800 , innerWidth:760 , opacity:0.7 }); return false;\"
                            href='inc/get_movie_details.php?m= $row->XD_ID' title='$row->FileText'>". squezzestring($row->FileText) ."</a></td>";
```

HTML output:

```
<a title="ti-t.le" href="inc/get_movie_details.php?m=12172" onclick="parent.$.colorbox({ href:'inc/get_movie_details.php?m=12172' , width:800 , maxWidth:800 , innerWidth:760 , opacity:0.7 }); return false;">ti-t.le</a>
```

It should display the link title here, but as you can see, it is emtpy. Everything else works as expected

HTML

```
<div id="cboxBottomCenter" style="float: left; width: 772px;"></div>
```

Comment: You shouldn't add javascript in the onclick attribute, attach it using getElementByID or jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here your working code: [jsfiddle.net/Ur5Kb/](http://jsfiddle.net/Ur5Kb/)

But better to use this [jsfiddle.net/Ur5Kb/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/Ur5Kb/1/):

```
$('a').colorbox({ href:'inc/get_movie_details.php?m=12172' , width:800 , maxWidth:800 , innerWidth:760 , opacity:0.7 });
```